# Binding in Control with "class" Attribute

Tags: css, sapui5

I want to handle the colors of the values in Text control (sap.m). If the value is `"TRUE"`, the color is green. Otherwise it will be red if the value is `"FALSE"`.

```xml
<Text
  class="{= ${HintTable>IS_ENABLED} === 'TRUE' ? 'greenTextColor' : redTextColor'}"
  text="{HintTable>IS_ENABLED}"
/>
```

But it doesn't seem to be working. I mean, the `class` cannot receive the `"greenTextColor"` nor `"redTextColor"`.

Did I make something wrong?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

UI5 [does not support](https://github.com/SAP/openui5/issues/58) binding for `class` in XML view *directly* as it's not a valid property of `ManagedObject`. However, there is a workaround by adding **custom data**:

1. Add `CustomData` with the property [`writeToDom`](https://sdk.openui5.org/api/sap.ui.core.CustomData#controlProperties) to your control. Use your expression binding there:

   ```xml
   <ControlXYZ class="myControl">
     <customData>
       <core:CustomData xmlns:core="sap.ui.core"
         writeToDom="{= expression }"
         key="green"
         value=""
       />
     </customData>
   </ControlXYZ>
   ```

   Depending on the outcome of your expression binding, `data-green` will be added to the control's HTML element. The browser can then manipulate the color corresponding to the [*attribute selector*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Attribute_selectors).
2. Your CSS should thus include the selector accordingly:

   ```css
   .myApp .sapControlXYZ.myControl[data-green] { /* ... */ }
   ```

Here is an **example: [https://embed.plnkr.co/LAv1qfsUjX0Anu7S/](https://embed.plnkr.co/LAv1qfsUjX0Anu7S?show=view%2FHome.view.xml,css%2Fstyle.css,preview:%3Fsap-ui-xx-componentPreload%3Doff)**

Of course, you can define a binding in `value="{...}"` too in order to increase the CSS specificity.

```css
.myApp .sapControlXYZ.myControl[data-green="someBoundValue"] { /* ... */ }
```

To learn more about how to leverage custom data in DOM, check out the documentation topic [Writing Data to the HTML DOM as DATA-* Attribute](https://sdk.openui5.org/topic/1ef9fefa2a574735957dcf52502ab8d0).

---

## ⚠️ Before using custom CSS..

There might be controls which don't require custom CSS. For example:

- [Text with *semantic* or *industry-specific* colors](https://experience.sap.com/fiori-design-web/how-to-use-semantic-colors/): `sap.m.ObjectStatus`, `.ObjectNumber`, etc.
- [Text with custom format](https://experience.sap.com/fiori-design-web/formatted-text/): `sap.m.FormattedText`.

[SAP explicitly warns](https://sdk.openui5.org/topic/91f087396f4d1014b6dd926db0e91070) not to use custom CSS styles.

> The HTML and **CSS generated by OpenUI5 isn't part of the public API** and may change in patch and minor releases. If you decide to override styles, you need to test and update your modifications each time OpenUI5 is updated. [...] As such, SAP **Fiori launchpad apps shouldn't override styles.**

Generally, the importance of adding custom CSS styles should be always questioned and double-checked with your stakeholders to improve the UI consistency across Fiori apps as well as to reduce the overall TCO.

Answer (score 1):

The answer of Boghyon Hoffmann is great!

But if none of his options should work for you, you can always resort to using two different copies of the `Text` element together with the `visible` attribute (which supports expression binding):

```
<Text
  class="greenTextColor"
  text="{HintTable>IS_ENABLED}"
  visible="{= ${HintTable>IS_ENABLED === 'TRUE'} }"
/>
<Text
  class="redTextColor"
  text="{HintTable>IS_ENABLED}"
  visible="{= ${HintTable>IS_ENABLED !== 'TRUE'} }"
/>
```

**Tipp:**
Simplify your expressions, if your model contains 
bools instead of strings:

```
  visible="{= ${HintTable>IS_ENABLED} }"
```

and

```
  visible="{= !${HintTable>IS_ENABLED} }"
```

Answer (score 0):

1. If you are using a local `JSONModel` for HintTable and the `IS_ENABLED` property is on the root level of the model you have to access it with a slash `"HintTable>/IS_ENABLED"`.
   Try it.
2. I'm not sure if you can bind class attributes. Never tried it.