# How to read all the tiles in the Tile Container SAP UI5

Tags: sapui5

```
<core:FragmentDefinition xmlns="sap.m"xmlns:f="sap.ui.layout.form" xmlns:core="sap.ui.core" xmlns:mvc="sap.ui.core.mvc"
    xmlns:html="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xmlns:l="sap.ui.layout">
 <Page id="tileInfo" showHeader="false" enableScrolling="true" > 
    <TileContainer    
      id="getTiles"

      tiles="{myModel1>TILECOLLECTION}">    
      <StandardTile 
        icon="{myModel1>icon}"  
        number="{myModel1>number}"  
        info="{myModel1>info}"
        infoState="{myModel1>infostate}" 
        title="{myModel1>title}" 
        numberUnit="{myModel1>numberunit}"
        press="handleTilePress"
        class="myGreen"    
        />   
        </TileContainer>   
       </Page> 
</core:FragmentDefinition>
```

I want to read each tile in the TileContainer in the view controller. Is it possible ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in the controller:

```
...
var oTileContainer = this.byId("getTiles");
var aTiles = oTileContainer.getTiles();
...
```

in the array aTiles are the tiles of the tiles aggregation of the tile container.

Comment: Since the "getTiles"  is in a fragment, I am not able to access it. Getting an error. Any thoughts ?

Comment: how do you invoke your fragment in your view?

Comment: I figured out the way to get tiles like you mentioned

var fragmentId = this.getView().createId("myFragment");
var tileContainer = sap.ui.core.Fragment.byId(fragmentId, "getTiles");
var tile = tileContainer.getTiles();

Lets say there are 10 tiles , how to read through each tile ?

Comment: for (var i = 0; i < oTiles.length; i++) { var oTile = oTiles[i]; // oTile is one tile of the tiles aggregation of the tiles container }

Comment: tileContainer has the values but oTiles length is 0 !.  Any mistake in var oTiles = tileContainer.getTiles();

Comment: wrote in the comment by mistake oTiles. wrote in the post correct aTiles. check whether you use aTiles or oTiles.

Comment: var fragmentId = this.getView().createId("myFragment");
                           var tileContainer = sap.ui.core.Fragment.byId(fragmentId,"getTiles");                          
                           var oTiles = tileContainer.getTiles();                          
                           console.log(tileContainer);


I checked  the console log for tileContainer and could see 10 tiles in magrregation. It is wierd that getTiles() does not get anything out of container !

Comment: weird. try: for (int i = 0; i < oTileContainer.mAggregations.tiles.length; i++) { console.log(oTileContainer.mAggregations.tiles[i]; }

Comment: Works now with.... it is wierd !
var oTileContainer = this.byId("getTiles");
var aTiles = oTileContainer.getTiles();

Answer (score 0):

Use nested views instead of fragment.
[code with nested views](http://plnkr.co/edit/VFLPaoQ8Knpdu0j6ZpSi?p=preview)

Then you can get the tiles and apply logic below.

```
var oTileContainer = this.byId("myView--getTiles");
var aTilesLength = oTileContainer.getTiles().length;
for(var i = 0 ;i<aTilesLength;i++){
  if(i%2 == 1){
  oTileContainer.getTiles()[i].addStyleClass("blue");
  }else{
   oTileContainer.getTiles()[i].addStyleClass("green"); 
  }  
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I have added a few more information. If we are not going byId we can use the below code to get the fragment details :

Thanks All.
Note :  The code does not work in onInit function but works in other functions

```
var fragmentId = this.getView().createId("myFragment");
var tileContainer = sap.ui.core.Fragment.byId(fragmentId,"getTiles");                               
 var oTiles = tileContainer.getTiles();
```