# UI5: change the style of list items after clicking on a button

Tags: css, sapui5

I want to dynamically change the style of a `sap.m.CustomListItem` of my list when I click on a button.

I used `addStyleClass` and it works only in the `onInit` method but not in the press` function, the style has been added but the view doesn't change.

## Controller

```js
pressbutton: function(oEvent) {
  var o = oEvent.getParameter("value");
  MessageToast.show(o.toString());
  var listitem = this.getView().byId("IDCustomerListItem");
  if (listitem.hasStyleClass("myListItemClass")) {
    this.getView().byId("IDCustomerListItem").removeStyleClass("myListItemClass");
    this.getView().byId("IDCustomerListItem").addStyleClass("myListItemClasso");
  } else {
    this.getView().byId("IDCustomerListItem").addStyleClass("myListItemClass"); 
  }
}
```

## CSS

```css
.myListItemClass {
  width: 50% !important;
  float: left;
}

.myListItemClasso {
  width: 100% !important;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a working example: [https://embed.plnkr.co/LAv1qfsUjX0Anu7S/](https://embed.plnkr.co/LAv1qfsUjX0Anu7S?show=view%2FHome.view.xml,preview).

---

### Why it didn't work

The reason why it worked only in `onInit` but not in the press handler is because the style was being applied to the **template control**. You probably have something like this in your view:

> ```xml
> <List xmlns="sap.m" items="{/myCollection}">
>   <CustomListItem id="IDCustomerListItem"> <!-- template control -->
>     <!-- ... -->
>   </CustomListItem>
> </List>
> ```

1. In `onInit`, the template control (`"IDCustomerListItem"`) applies the custom style, and then the framework **clones** the template control for each collection item before rendering.
2. In the press handler, however, applying the style to the template control doesn't have any effects any longer since the list items have been already cloned and rendered. It won't trigger cloning again.

The sample solution I provided above applies the style to the list. When the user triggers an action (via Switch for example), the render manager adds a custom data attribute to the corresponding HTML element by which the CSS can be applied accordingly.

```css
.myApp .sapMList.myList[data-awesomestyle] .sapMLIB {
  /* my custom style */
}
```

See [Binding in Control with "class" Attribute](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42221962/binding-in-control-with-class-attribute/42232902)

Answer (score 0):

If it works in the onInit but not inside your `pressbutton` event handler, I assume the following:

1) The handler is not assigned to the press event of your `Button`

2) Your list has many items and you are not correctly getting the IDs of the items.

It's confusing in your question what are the controls assigned to the IDs and it would be easier to check the root cause of that issue having the source code of your view as well.