# How to add and use a custom style class in SAPUI5

Tags: css, sapui5

I am new to SAPUI5 and would like to change the text color of a label to red. How can I do this?

I tried:

```js
sap.ui.getCore().byId("lableID").setStyleClass("red");
```

but the color does not change.

Comment: See the section "⚠️ Before using custom CSS.." at https://stackoverflow.com/a/42232902/5846045.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add a style.css file under webapp > css to your project. The style.css file could look like this:

```
.red {
    color: red;
}
```